# Protractor - getting value of a cookie

Tags: protractor

I have a cookie value which can change every time I load a page - and I want to capture this.

```
it('test get a value back', function() {

    var sessionID;

    // add a delay in to cover waiting for page to render
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var e  = element(by.css(constants.cookieAccept));
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(e),10000);

    // click the accept
    element(by.css(constants.cookieAccept)).click();

    var EC2 = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var e2  = element(by.xpath(constants.IYSDyesRadio));
    browser.wait(EC2.presenceOf(e2),10000);


    // this variable returns undefined
    browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
        sessionID = cookie.value;
    });

    // this expectation fails (the value returened cookie.value is correct)
    browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
        expect(cookie.value).toEqual("Yes");
    });

    console.log('Session id is ' + sessionID);

});
```

Above is my little test code.  I am trying to get the value from the "mycookie" cookie and assign this to the sessionID variable - however on execution this is undefined.  I use the next piece of code where I compare the value against a string returns the correct cookie value.

I can't quite see what I am doing wrong. I suspect it's something sily with promises.

I've now commented out one of the cookie elements and am just using console.log on the cookie value and the correct value is appearing on the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments are not too readable. Let me elaborate the issue here.

```
browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
    console.log(cookie.value) //print the value
    sessionID = cookie.value; //assign a value
});
```

If you will do:
    console.log(sessionID)
    it won't work.

`getCookie()` returns a promise. So if you want to use `sessionID` you need to wait for it (using another `then()`).

So the code should look like that:

```
browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
    console.log(cookie.value) //print the value
    sessionID = cookie.value; //assign a value
}).then(() => {
    console.log(sessionID, ' it works!');
});
```

Comment: thanks - I think I was getting confused with a) promised and b) trying to interpret the formatting of the commentws

Answer (score 0):

The `expect` line should be moved inside the `.then` block. If you are setting a value from the resolved promise you are not guaranteed that it will be done before following lines of code.

I am not fully sure I understood your question but the following code should work:

```
browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
    expect('the expected cookie value').toEqual(cookie.value);
});
```

Comment: I'll try and explain better.  I have a cookie on my machine which will have a randoim string.  I want to be able to get the contents of this.

       var sessionID = "meh"
        browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
            //sessionID = cookie.value;
            console.log('>> ' + cookie.value);
            sessionID + "--" + cookie.value;
        });


        console.log('Session id is ' + sessionID);

So i'd expect the output to be "Session id is meh--<random>"

Comment: Due to the asynchronous nature of the code, the console log (and any code) outside the the .then block will execute before code inside the .then block.

Comment: yeah - but all i want to do is to have the cookie value assigned to a variable.  It isn't working - the variable never gets set

Comment: It is assigned, as @M Mansour said. try that:     // this variable returns undefined
    browser.manage().getCookie('mycookie').then(function(cookie) {
        sessionID = cookie.value;
    }).then(() => {console.log(sessionID)});

Comment: `        browser.manage().getCookie('sepa').then(function(cookie) {
            //sessionID = cookie.value;
            console.log('>> ' + cookie.value);
            sessionID + "--" + cookie.value;
        });`